# Determine the area of the region $y + \cos x = 1.$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> Determine the area of the region $y + \cos x = 1.$ Disregard the unit of area.

Attempt: It's a curve not a region. If you mean the area between the graph and the $x$-as between two consecutive roots then it is $\int_0^{2\pi} (1-\cos x)\:dx=2\pi$.

But the answer is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$. What if for example is $y + \cos\alpha= 1$?

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct, I think it's an error on the exercise's behalf. One implicitly defined curve is not enough to define a region, as you noted. The graph of all $(x,y)$ such that $y+\cos(x)=1$ is just that of $y=\cos(x)$ shifted by $1$ on the y-axis; one could argue there's an infinite area between it and the x-axis since it is tangent to infinitely many points of it: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tqedkycjii

Comment: The region is simply not specified. You need to tell us the bounds for $x$, or some other way to determine what the region is.